# Find two binary numbers with a multiplication of a specific form

Tags: binary

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this question but I tried to search online, wasn't able to find anything useful.

Consider binary numbers of the form $$x=0|y|0|y$$ 
where $a|b$ means concatenate the bits of $a$ with the bits of $b$, $y$ is any sequence of bits of size $n$.

Is it possible to find three binary numbers $s_1,s_2,s\neq 0$ of the previous form such that $s_1.s_2=s$ where $.$ is just the plain multiplication operator? If not why?

Obviously, all of $s_1,s_2,s$ need to be of size $\leq 2n+2$ bits

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $x = (2^{n}+1)y$. If you consider $2^n+1$ to be of the desired form, then we're done. Otherwise, this factorization places some constraints on your desired $s$.

Comment: This will require $y$ to be of size greater than $n$ thou, since it need to be of that form too

Comment: @Shadowfirex:  no.  Consider $y=11_2=3_{10}$.  Then $x=11011_2=27_{10}=3\cdot 9$

Comment: Sorry I noticed the question says "two numbers" I edited that. I meant all of $s_1,s_2,s$ are of that form, for $y=11_2$ it's not the case.

Comment: @Shadowfirex:  and how about $y=101_2=5_{10}, x=1010101_2=85_{10}=5\cdot 17$

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot!